# Does Eclipse Neon support Java 11?

Tags: java-11, eclipse-neon

I ma trying to add JDK 11 with eclipse Neon, but it gives error- Target is not a jdk root
"[image]"

Comment: No, it is too old and does not understand the revised layout of the JDK in newer Javas.

Comment: Thanks.. I just installed eclipse 2020-03. It worked.

Comment: @RahulJain True but Eclipse 2020-03 isn't Eclipse Neon (4.6). I just came across your post after encountering a similar incompatibility between Eclipse Neon and Java 17. Eclipse simply refused to start.